# phpMyAdmin displays error when importing database 2

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm cloning a WordPress into my PC. I have already backed up all files.. The problem is that when I try and import the database using phpMyAdmin, I get this error message:
Error

### Query SQL:

### -- Dump dei dati per la tabella `wp_commentmeta`

INSERT INTO `wp_commentmeta` (`meta_id`, `comment_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES
(3, 9, '_wp_trash_meta_status', '0')
Messaggio di MySQL:

## 1062 - Valore duplicato '3' per la chiave 'PRIMARY'

Could someone help me with any advice? Please

Answer (score 0):

try dropping all the tables in the database before importing into it....make sure that you don't need any of the data in that database though...